# Python on osx, Why can't it see the libraries?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I'm a little confused.

I have two machines running OSX Yosemite.

I have installed certain python libraries using pip

Now on one, these have wound up in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

And they perform exactly as expected.

On the other, they have found their way into /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Now, on that machine, if I run a script that imports these libraries directly from the command line, it fails to find them.

So

```
Myscript.py
```

fails (with an importError)

But, if I run it as a parameter to a call to python, that's fine

```
python MyScript.py
```

works as expected.

I've compared the sheband with the path I get from

```
whereis python
```

and they match.

What might be causing this discrepancy?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I've half found the answer, two different versions of python are running. Which then begs the question, why?

i've put that into a new, more focused question here

[Why is OSX not running the python I get with whereis python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401685/why-is-osx-not-running-the-python-i-get-with-whereis-python)