# Why is OSX not running the python I get with whereis python

Tags: python, macos

I have a machine running OSX Yosemite (it has been through several versions of OSX, which may make a difference).

I noticed an anomily with whether python could import libraries depending on whether the script was run directly, i.e.

```
./Myscript.py
```

Or by expressly calling python

```
python Myscript.py
```

Now, if I type

```
$whereis python
/usr/bin/python
```

And my shebang line in the script is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

So I assumed that the same version of python was running in both cases.

But after investigating I find

```
$python --version
Python 2.7.6
$/usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

So it would seem that the python being executed is not the one I get when I do a whereis

Can anyone please shed some light on this, and also clarify how to fix it? I really want to be running 2.7.10 in both cases, since right now when I install libraries they go into 2.7.6, but when I run scripts, they run 2.7.10 and can't see the libraries.

Thanks

Jon

Comment: You should use `which python`, not `whereis`.

Comment: Thanks, that at least shows the correct version..

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `whereis`, that command *ignores your `PATH` environment variable*. From the manpage:

> The `whereis` utility checks the ***standard binary directories*** for the specified programs, printing out the paths of any it finds.

Emphasis mine.

You have a `PATH` environment variable that includes a 'nonstandard' binary directory. Use `which` to find where `python` comes from:

```
$ which python
```

`which` gives you the *actual binary used* for your current shell configuration:

> The `which` utility takes a list of command names and searches the path for each executable file ***that would be run had these commands actually been invoked.***

You could use `which -a` to find all possible completions for the command:

```
$ which -a python
```

Also see [*“whereis” and “which” return different paths in Mac OS X*](https://superuser.com/questions/430002/whereis-and-which-return-different-paths-in-mac-os-x) on Super User.

Demo:

```
$ PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH whereis python
/usr/bin/python
$ PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH which -a python
/opt/homebrew/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

So even with `PATH` *explicitly* pointing to my homebrew directory, `whereis` ignores it. `which` finds it and lists it first (the `-a` argument made it look for more options).